# Example of using "lid" in JSON:API

Tags: json-api

The [spec for JSON:API v1.1](https://jsonapi.org/format/1.1/) mentions that "when the resource object originates at the client and represents a new resource to be created on the server", "a lid member may be included to uniquely identify the resource by type locally within the document".

However, when creating a new resource, "the request must include a single resource object".

So, it seems the only case where "lid" might be useful is to create a resource with a relationship to itself.

Is this correct? Else, what would another example be?

Comment: After asking Google for a while, I grilled ChatGPT until it told me it's for "batch creation" of multiple resources, which was my initial motivation for investigating "lid", and I believe it was also the JSON:API authors' initial motivation, but it doesn't appear in (the version 1.1 of) the spec.